# Image Slider in Umbraco 5 jupiter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, jquery-slider

I have to create an image slider in Umbraco 5, user will provide me images from the admin panel and there must be no limit on then number of images and user can enter some teext about these images also, i know i can pick all the images from a specific folder in Media Section but i dont know how the user will add text, is this the best way to do that or there is some other way.

(and it would be great if i can restrict the dimensions of the image)

Thanks in Advance,

Sher

Solution:

Thanks For the Reply the solution for this specific issue is on this link

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/umbraco-5-general-discussion/30787-Image-Slider-with-text-in-Umbraco-5-jupiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was looking to add all my images in the Media Gallery and creating new pages in not an option for me (client), i found the solution on this post actually which suites best for me,

[Image Slider with text in Umbraco 5 jupiter](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/umbraco-5-general-discussion/30787-Image-Slider-with-text-in-Umbraco-5-jupiter)

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is to create a document type for the slide. Then add properties as needed, e.g. Image (media picker), text etc.
Create another document type called slides, no properties, with some template.

Then create a content node to hold your slides using the slides document type and template. Then create a few slide document types under the node you just created. So now you can just iterate through the .Children of the slides node.

Works for me.